# Quotient of a quadratic integer ring is finite

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is square-free. Show that $R/I$ is finite.

This, presumably, follows from the fact that for any non-zero $r\in R$ there is some non-zero $s\in R$ such that $rs$ is an integer. My suspicion is that this is actually straight-forward and I'm just missing something simple, but regardless I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a non-zero $x+y\sqrt n \in I$ and define $$c := (x+y\sqrt n)(x-y\sqrt n) = x^2-ny^2,$$
so $0 \neq c \in \mathbb Z \cap I$. Then we have the inclusions
$$cR \subseteq I \subseteq R$$
which implies
$$\operatorname{rank}(cR) \leq \operatorname{rank}(I) \leq \operatorname{rank}(R).$$
Since $R = \mathbb Z + \sqrt n \mathbb Z$ and $cR = c\mathbb Z + c\sqrt n \mathbb Z$ are both abelian groups of rank $2$, the same holds for $I$. So $R/I$ is a finitely generated abelian group of rank $0$, hence finite.

Comment: Once you have $I\subseteq cR$, you could alternatively immediately conclude $\#(R/I)\leq\#(R/cR)=c^2$, with as bonus a measure of finiteness.